# Any bibliographic reference for description of venetian blind cross validation method?

Tags: cross-validation, references

I need a complete description of venetian blind cross validation method,

Comment: Potential close voters: Anyone else tempted to agree with the *off-topic* vote -- please explain (via comment) *why* you think a question about *cross validation* would be off topic on *Cross Validated*. Such an apparent contradiction (it's right there in our name!) requires justification. While this question has some problems and might arguably need to be placed on hold until they're resolved (e.g. it's potentially too broad as it stands, and possibly unclear), I'd have thought that its on-topicness would have been beyond dispute. [Unless it was a misclick -- *off topic* is next to *unclear*]

Comment: It would help if you told us what references you have currently found and in what respect they fail to do what you had hoped for then perhaps someone more knowledgeable than me can guide you.

Comment: I don't see how this can be off topic or too broad. Gonzalo is not asking for a solution, he is asking for a reference.  Surely someone who knows about venetian blind cross validation could supply a few references without it even being a long answer.

Comment: I don't think the question is off-topic or too broad, but I flagged it as unclear (declined). There is a question on the title ("Any bibliographic *reference* for description of venetian blind cross validation method?") and a request ("I need a complete *description* of venetian blind cross validation method") in the post. Which one is asked about, reference or description? I think the question is still unclear and OP should provide more information.

Comment: @T.E.G.: I understand this to ask for a proper reference that gives a full description. I.e. a paper merely saying that they use Venetian blinds cross validation and from which you may be able to guess what it means is not enough. And neiter is a full description in an answer here that is not from a peer-reviewed paper or book.